# Evaluating $\int_\gamma z(1+|z|^2)^{-1/2}\,|dz|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Let $\gamma(t)=te^{it}$ for $0 \leq t \leq \pi$.

I want to evaluate 
$$
\int_\gamma z(1+\left|z\right|^2)^{-1/2}\,\left|dz\right|.
$$
Substituting and simplifying we have:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}te^{it}(1+t^2)^{-1/2}\left|tie^{it}+e^{it}\right|\,dt=\int_{0}^{\pi}te^{it}(1+t^2)^{-1/2}\left(t^2+1\right)\,dt=\int_{0}^{\pi}te^{it}(1+t^2)^{1/2}\,dt$$

Is there some sort of trick that I can use to approach the last integral?  I don't have the advantage of being able to use residues or Cauchy's various theorems, so I'm looking for a calculus trick so I can solve this by hand.

Comment: You have a small but crucial error here: $|t i e^{it}+e^{it}|=(1+t^2)^{1/2}$. Making this correction will simplify the integral.

Answer (score 1):

$$
dz=(\mathrm{e}^{it}+it\mathrm{e}^{it})\,dt,
$$
and thus
$$
|dz|=\sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt.
$$
tHus you have
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{z\,dz}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}}=\int_0^\pi \frac{t\mathrm{e}^{it}\sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\int_0^\pi t\mathrm{e}^{it}\,dt=(-it+1)\mathrm{e}^{it}\big|_0^\pi=\cdots.
$$